# Help I have problem with select query in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

i have problem i want to

select name_magazine from magazine

and i already import all library needed

and

> Query q = EntityManger.createQuery ("SELECT name_magazine FROM Magazine");
>
> List results = (List) q.getResultList ();
>
> For(Sting s : result)
>
> System.out.println(s);

but when i run this code it's error. can someone help me? Thx

this the error when i run the program

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.Error:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionFailed(ApplicationAction.java:859)
>           at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:665)
>           at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.actionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:698)
>           at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
>           at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>           at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>           at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1220)
>           at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1261)
>           at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
>           at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6041)
>           at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
>           at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5806)
>           at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4413)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4243)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
>           at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
>           at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
>           at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2440)
>           at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4243)
>           at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
>           at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.jdesktop.application.ApplicationAction.noProxyActionPerformed(ApplicationAction.java:662)
>           ... 29 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An
>   exception occured while creating a
>   query in EntityManager
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:209)
>           at tugas_rpl.Tugas_RPLView.Iseng(Tugas_RPLView.java:734)
>           ... 34 more Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-8034] (Oracle
>   TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build
>   b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))):
>   oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EJBQLException
>   Exception Description: Error compiling
>   the query [Select m.Name from
>   magazine m]. Unknown abstract schema type
>   [magazine].
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EJBQLException.unknownAbstractSchemaType(EJBQLException.java:494)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.ParseTreeContext.classForSchemaName(ParseTreeContext.java:163)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.VariableNode.resolveClass(VariableNode.java:280)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.DotNode.resolveMapping(DotNode.java:254)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.DotNode.endsWithDirectToField(DotNode.java:213)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.SelectNode.selectingDirectToField(SelectNode.java:440)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.SelectNode.hasOneToOneSelected(SelectNode.java:265)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.SelectNode.hasOneToOneSelected(SelectNode.java:222)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.SelectGenerationContext.computeUseParallelExpressions(SelectGenerationContext.java:105)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.SelectGenerationContext.(SelectGenerationContext.java:88)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.ParseTree.buildContextForReadQuery(ParseTree.java:382)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.ParseTree.buildContext(ParseTree.java:370)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.EJBQLParseTree.buildContext(EJBQLParseTree.java:68)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.parsing.EJBQLParseTree.populateQuery(EJBQLParseTree.java:107)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:219)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:189)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:153)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:114)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.base.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:99)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EJBQueryImpl.(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
>           at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:204)
>           ... 35 more

I already try Vincent Ramdhanie,Guðmundur Bjarni suggestion

> Query q = entityManager.createQuery("Select m.name from magazine m");
>
> List result = (List) q.getResultList();
>
> For(Sting s : result)
>
> System.out.print(s);

but still error

this what library & variable i use

> private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
>
> import org.jdesktop.application.Action;
>
> import org.jdesktop.application.ResourceMap;
>
> import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;
>
> import org.jdesktop.application.FrameView;
>
> import org.jdesktop.application.TaskMonitor;
>
> import org.jdesktop.application.Task;
>
> import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
>
> import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
>
> import java.util.List;
>
> import javax.swing.Timer;
>
> import javax.swing.Icon;
>
> import javax.swing.JDialog;
>
> import javax.swing.JFrame;
>
> import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
>
> import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
>
> import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AbstractBindingListener;
>
> import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding;
>
> import org.jdesktop.beansbinding.PropertyStateEvent;
>
> import javax.persistence.*;

Comment: Perhaps if you studied the stacktrace, as danvinton suggests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327487/help-i-have-problem-with-select-query-in-jpa#327764

Comment: Ok, Problem Solve. i have found the other way. thx

Answer (score 2):

You probably should say what the error is exactly.

However, assuming that you have an entity Magazine then the query should be:

```
 select m from Magazine m
```

If you want all magazines.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right there in the call stack for your exception:

```
Error compiling the query [Select m.Jenis_Motor from motor m]. Unknown abstract schema type [motor].
```

It's not a problem with your magazine query, but another malformed query - probably a named query defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need an entity defined as such:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "magazines")
public class Magazine {
  /*
   * Some more attributes
   */

  @Column(name = "name_magazine")
  private String name;

  /*
   * Constructors, getters and setters
   */
}
```

Additionally you need a persistence.xml file pointing to your entity. If all of that is in place, this query should work and give you a list of all magazines.

```
from Magazine m
```

The query you specified is a projection of that, and with the entity I showed above it should be

```
select m.name from Magazine m
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you rename your class?

The class name may differ from the name used in the named query

Answer (score 0):

If You are using JPA then in Query You need to write className and object as follows

```
Query q = EntityManger.createQuery ("SELECT name_magazine e FROM Magazine e");
```

e is an object of Magazine class.
and if you facing this exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager
Check out your persistance.xml file you need to add class in this file after the persistence-unit tag

```
<class>PackageName.className</class>
```